# Import MTX files into R

Tags: python, r, pandas, scipy

I have a large hdf file from which I get one of the data-frame and convert it into Sparse Matrix in python (sparse.csr_matrix). Now, I save this as .MTX file and trying to load this in R. I went through some documentation and links for loading MTX files into R using externalFormats {Matrix}. Unfortunately, I get the following error.

```
TestDataMatrix = readMM(system.file("./Downloads/TestDataMatrix.mtx",
                                package = "Matrix"))
```

When I run the above code, I get the following error and I have no clue what it means.

```
 TestDataMatrix = readMM(system.file("./Downloads/TestDataMatrix.mtx",
+                                 package = "Matrix"))
1:
```

Could someone let me know if there is an easy way to convert python objects to R objects (like RDS).

Comment: It seems like you pasted the code twice and did not include the error message. Could you edit your question ?

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the error message I have received. There was nothing   after 1: as shown in the above code

Comment: Is there a way to close the question? I found a way to read hdf files in R and got the data-frame converted to Sparse-Matrix

Comment: You could answer your own question, so that when someone finds this question, she will have the answer.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I found a way to read hdf files in R and got the data-frame converted to Sparse-Matrix. But there is a problem writing to HDF files. I posted a new question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46699906/writing-very-large-files-to-hdf-in-r?noredirect=1#comment80347687_46699906).

Comment: Could you describe the solution you found? Thanks!